# Save user information in SESSION not working .PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session

so am on way to save user data into session. I have set up first username and memberID which looks like working properly. but once I have added more details to save session won't read them in othter pages. Session starts in database connection. I don't know where is problem and hope for help from you guys. Thanks

```
if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {

$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
$_SESSION['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];
$_SESSION['loggedin_time'] = time(); 

return true;
}
```

Code I'am adding in php page:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['email'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>
```

FIXED

My statement had only selecting memberID and username!!!

Comment: did you used at the first line of your page `session_start();`?

Comment: My session starts when I connect to database, I have mentioned that memberID and username can be read but other information no.

Comment: then `print_r($row)` to see whether it contains the email or avatar information.

Comment: ```print_r($_SESSION['email']``` shows 1 same on avatar

Answer (score 0):

Always remember to use `session_start()`, to set or use it. Remember to do it in the top of your .PHP file.

**First php page**

```php
session_start();

if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {

$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
$_SESSION['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];
$_SESSION['loggedin_time'] = time(); 

return true;
}
```

**Another php page**

```php
session_start();

...
```

**Note**: if this isn't the case, you should try to do a `var_dump()` on the two variables, and see if there is any information stored in them.

Comment: My session start when I connect to database. I forgot to add it to description.

Comment: Try to do a var_dump() on the array

Comment: ```var_dump``` on ```$_SESSION['email']``` shows NULL

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` output?

Comment: Problem has been fixed. My statement to MySQL was reading only memberID and username.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Problem was that I had statement to select only memberID and username in my PDO!!!